# Angular 2: Get ViewContainerRef of dynamically inserted anchor template

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-components

I'm trying to implement a portlet layout where user can drag and drop the widgets on to the dropzone. [Example](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#layout_portal_manual). The dropzone initially looks like the following:

```
<div class="container portlet-layout"></div>
```

When user drag and drop the widget on to the dropzone (see the layout image below)

[image]

I will insert the template with unique ID with other information like ROW + COLUMN (position in the layout) etc...

```
  **in code**

onDrop(event: MouseEvent) {
   let target = event.target;
       comp = target['__comp'];

   this._portletBody.innerHTML = `<div class="row"> //Note: the innerHTML is for example only, I use appendChild to insert the child if COLUMN is already exisit
         <div class="col">
           <template #ROW_1_COL_1></template>
         </div>
      </div>`;

   this.cfr.resolveComponentFactory(comp);

   //How to get the inserted "ROW_1_COL_1" templateRef?
}
*** result ***
<div class="container portlet-layout">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col">
           <template #ROW_1_COL_1></template>
         </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Question: How to get the newly inserted `templateRef`? I have tried to use `ViewChild` and `ViewChildren`, `ViewChild` works only it exist by the time `AfterViewInit` called and `ViewChildren` returns null. Could you someone help me how to get the newly inserted (dynamically using `innerHTML/appendChild`) `templateRef`? If I have to different technique to insert the dynamic content please do point me to doc's to refer.

**Edit**

Basically I want to add dynamic anchor where I can insert the component.

Comment: could you please reproduce it with a plunker? a small example is needed as your code is incomplete and hard to identify how things are working together.

Comment: I have shared the [Git repo](https://github.com/manju-reddys/Portlet-Layout). See the code in ``portlet-layout.component.ts => onChartTypeDrop``

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: Yes, but I used different technic to solve the problem, I will commit the changes to the git (see previous comment).